# typo3 scheduler works only manually

Tags: typo3, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, typo3-9.x

I have some problems with the scheduler of typo3 9.5.5. I already set up a few jobs (e.g. ke_seach indexing every 2 mins) and they do work if I start them manually. But the automatic execution does not work. The backend module just shows "late" and nothing else  happens.

It seems that there is also nothing in the logs.
The backend user "_cli_scheduler" was created (first without and currently with admin rigths) but this user never gets a login.

System:
Typo3 9.5.5 on a virtual machine (Centos 7).
The webserver is a xampp/lampp package running as localhost/

.htaccess (if necessary):

```
#####
#
# Example .htaccess file for TYPO3 CMS - for use with Apache Webserver
#
# This file includes settings for the following configuration options:
#
# - Compression
# - Caching
# - MIME types
# - Cross Origin requests
# - Rewriting and Access
# - Miscellaneous
# - PHP optimisation
#
# If you want to use it, you have to copy it to the root folder of your TYPO3 installation (if its
# not there already) and rename it to '.htaccess'. To make .htaccess files work, you might need to
# adjust the 'AllowOverride' directive in your Apache configuration file.
#
# IMPORTANT: You may need to change this file depending on your TYPO3 installation!
#            Consider adding this file's content to your webserver's configuration directly for speed improvement
#
# Lots of the options are taken from https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess
#
####


### Begin: Compression ###

# Compressing resource files will save bandwidth and so improve loading speed especially for users
# with slower internet connections. TYPO3 can compress the .js and .css files for you.
# *) Uncomment the following lines and
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 for the Backend
# *) Set $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['compressionLevel'] = 9 together with the TypoScript properties
#    config.compressJs and config.compressCss for GZIP compression of Frontend JS and CSS files.

# gzip is also  in line 363
#<FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
#<FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
#   AddType "text/css" .gzip
#</FilesMatch>
AddEncoding gzip .gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    #
    # (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
    # enable `mod_filter` and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>`
    # and `</IfModule>` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
    # the core directives.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
            application/javascript \
            application/json \
            application/ld+json \
            application/manifest+json \
            application/rdf+xml \
            application/rss+xml \
            application/schema+json \
            application/vnd.geo+json \
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
            application/x-font-ttf \
            application/x-javascript \
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
            application/xhtml+xml \
            application/xml \
            font/eot \
            font/opentype \
            image/bmp \
            image/svg+xml \
            image/vnd.microsoft.icon \
            image/x-icon \
            text/cache-manifest \
            text/css \
            text/html \
            text/javascript \
            text/plain \
            text/vcard \
            text/vnd.rim.location.xloc \
            text/vtt \
            text/x-component \
            text/x-cross-domain-policy \
            text/xml
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip svgz
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

### End: Compression ###



### Begin: Browser caching of resource files ###

# This affects Frontend and Backend and increases performance.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>

### End: Browser caching of resource files ###


### Begin: MIME types ###

# Proper MIME types for all files
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    # Data interchange
    AddType application/atom+xml                        atom
    AddType application/json                            json map topojson
    AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld
    AddType application/rss+xml                         rss
    AddType application/vnd.geo+json                    geojson
    AddType application/xml                             rdf xml

    # JavaScript
    AddType application/javascript                      js

    # Manifest files
    AddType application/manifest+json                   webmanifest
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache

    # Media files

    AddType audio/mp4                                   f4a f4b m4a
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus
    AddType image/bmp                                   bmp
    AddType image/svg+xml                               svg svgz
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv
    AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico

    # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/font-woff2                      woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

    # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-bb-appworld                   bbaw
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType text/vcard                                  vcard vcf
    AddType text/vnd.rim.location.xloc                  xloc
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc

</IfModule>

# UTF-8 encoding
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .manifest .rdf .rss .vtt .webapp .webmanifest .xml
</IfModule>

### End: MIME types ###



### Begin: Cross Origin ###

# Send the CORS header for images when browsers request it.
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Allow cross-origin access to web fonts.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

### End: Cross Origin ###



### Begin: Rewriting and Access ###

# You need rewriting, if you use a URL-Rewriting extension (RealURL, CoolUri).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # Store the current location in an environment variable CWD to use
    # mod_rewrite in .htaccess files without knowing the RewriteBase
    RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

    # Rules to set ApplicationContext based on hostname
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production/Staging]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    #RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Production]

    # Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # - $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
    # IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!

### Begin: Static File Cache (preparation) ####

# Document root configuration
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_ROOT:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}]
# RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_ROOT:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/t3site] # Example if your installation is installed in a directory

# Cleanup URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_URI:/%{REQUEST_URI}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*$
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_URI:/]

# Cleanup HOST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_HOST:%1]

# Get scheme
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_PROTOCOL:https]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_PROTOCOL:http]

# Get port (not used at the moment)
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_PORT:80]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^[0-9]*$ [OR]
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_PORT:%{SERVER_PORT}]

# Check if the requested file exists in the cache, otherwise default to index.html that
# set in an environment variable that is used later on
RewriteCond %{ENV:SFC_ROOT}/typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache/%{ENV:SFC_PROTOCOL}/%{ENV:SFC_HOST}%{ENV:SFC_URI} !-f
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_FILE:index.html]

# Note: https://github.com/lochmueller/staticfilecache/pull/90 (Please check the realurl configuration related to "appendMissingSlash". Perhaps you need an additional "/" in the rule above)
# RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_FILE:/index.html]

# Set gzip extension into an environment variable if the visitors browser can handle gzipped content and the gz-file exists
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_GZIP:]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_GZIP:.gz]
RewriteCond %{ENV:SFC_ROOT}/typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache/%{ENV:SFC_PROTOCOL}/%{ENV:SFC_HOST}%{ENV:SFC_URI}%{ENV:SFC_FILE}%{ENV:SFC_GZIP} !-f
RewriteRule .* - [E=SFC_GZIP:]

# Note: We cannot check realurl "appendMissingSlash" or other BE related settings here - in front of the delivery.
# Perhaps you have to check the "SFC_FILE" value and set it to your related configution e.g. "index.html" (without leading slash).
# More information at: https://github.com/lochmueller/staticfilecache/pull/28

### Begin: Static File Cache (main) ####

# We only redirect URI's without query strings
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

# It only makes sense to do the other checks if a static file actually exists.
RewriteCond %{ENV:SFC_ROOT}/typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache/%{ENV:SFC_PROTOCOL}/%{ENV:SFC_HOST}%{ENV:SFC_URI}%{ENV:SFC_FILE}%{ENV:SFC_GZIP} -f

# NO frontend or backend user is logged in. Logged in users may see different
# information than anonymous users. But the anonymous version is cached. So
# don't show the anonymous version to logged in users.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !staticfilecache [NC]

# Uncomment the following line if you use MnoGoSearch
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-TYPO3-mnogosearch} ^$

# We only redirect GET requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET

# Rewrite the request to the static file.
RewriteRule .* %{ENV:SFC_ROOT}/typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache/%{ENV:SFC_PROTOCOL}/%{ENV:SFC_HOST}%{ENV:SFC_URI}%{ENV:SFC_FILE}%{ENV:SFC_GZIP} [L]

# Do not allow direct call the cache entries
RewriteCond %{ENV:SFC_URI} ^/typo3temp/tx_staticfilecache/.*
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

### Begin: Static File Cache (options) ####

# Set proper content type and encoding for gzipped html.
<FilesMatch "\.gz">
   SetEnv no-gzip 1
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
   </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# if there are same problems with ForceType, please try the AddType alternative
# Set proper content type gzipped html
<FilesMatch "\.html\.gz">
   ForceType text/html
   # AddType "text/html" .gz
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.xml\.gz">
   ForceType text/xml
   # AddType "text/xml" .gz
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.rss\.gz">
   ForceType text/xml
   # AddType "text/xml" .gz
</FilesMatch>

### End: Static File Cache ###

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ %{ENV:CWD}$1.$3 [L]

    # Access block for folders
    RewriteRule _(?:recycler|temp)_/ - [F]
    RewriteRule fileadmin/templates/.*\.(?:txt|ts)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|typo3_src|typo3temp/var) - [F]
    RewriteRule (?:typo3conf/ext|typo3/sysext|typo3/ext)/[^/]+/(?:Configuration|Resources/Private|Tests?|Documentation|docs?)/ - [F]

    # Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
    # the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory (RFC 5785).
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule (?:^|/)\. - [F]

    # Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
    # NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
    RewriteRule ^(?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

    # If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
    # For httpd.conf, you need to prefix each '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' with '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}'.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# Access block for files
# Apache < 2.3
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    <FilesMatch "(?i:^\.|^#.*#|^(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|^composer\.(?:json|lock)|^ext_conf_template\.txt|^ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|^ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*)|.*(?:~|rc))$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# Apache ≥ 2.3
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(?i:/\.|/\x23.*\x23|/(?:ChangeLog|ToDo|Readme|License)(?:\.md|\.txt)?|/composer\.(?:json|lock)|/ext_conf_template\.txt|/ext_typoscript_constants\.txt|/ext_typoscript_setup\.txt|flexform[^.]*\.xml|locallang[^.]*\.(?:xml|xlf)|\.(?:bak|co?nf|cfg|ya?ml|ts|typoscript|tsconfig|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|sh|sql(?:\..*)?|sqlite(?:\..*)?|sw[op]|git.*)|.*(?:~|rc))$#">
        Require all denied
    </If>
</IfModule>

# Block access to vcs directories
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.(?:git|svn|hg)/
</IfModule>

### End: Rewriting and Access ###



### Begin: Miscellaneous ###

# 404 error prevention for non-existing redirected folders
Options -MultiViews

# Make sure that directory listings are disabled.
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Force IE to render pages in the highest available mode
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff2?|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

    # Reducing MIME type security risks
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# ETag removal
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None

### End: Miscellaneous ###


# Add your own rules here.
```

Comment: Can you please confirm, that you have set up a cronjob to execute the scheduler? See [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/stable/Installation/CronJob/Index.html) for further details.

Comment: The cronjob mentioned above is mandatory, but it might be tricky to get it running under windows. Regarding the `_cli_scheduler` user: this on is obsolete since TYPO3 8.7. See [changelog](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79240-SingleCliUserForCliCommands.html).

Comment: After Michaels comment I checked "crontab -e" and it was empty. So I added this line: */5 * * * * root /opt/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 . I also deleted the backend user "_cli_scheduler" and everything works now. Thanks for your help, the topic can be closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please confirm, that you have set up a cronjob to execute the scheduler? See documentation for further details. – Michael

Exactly this was the problem, so the following steps solved the problem:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This opened vim and after pressing "i" the following line was inserted:

```
*/6 * * * * /opt/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run
```

After save and exit ([Esc], :x [Enter]) finally the cron daemon was restartet:

```
sudo systemctl restart crond.service
```

Everything works now.

I made this post because it seems to be not possible to mark a comment as a solution.
Thanks everyone for (really quick) help.

Comment: Is there still a way to point to a PHP file over HTTP? (Like EXT:scheduler_http was doing, but this extension is outdated). Unfortunately some hoster don't allow `crontab` access, so they provide only a webinterface.